# Java - Custom JDialog dispose method called more than once - it is not intended to do so

Tags: java, dispose, jdialog

I am working on a script which involves JDialogs popping up consecutively to ask the user to capture information on the screen (such as boxes around a menu, etc) so the program would afterwards automatically click where I designate it to.

The problem I am currently stuck on is that when I close my custom JDialog, the dispose method is seemingly called multiple times, although I have no idea why.

Here is a complete working example of the issue:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {

    // Creates the main frame (MainForm extends JFrame)
    private static MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainForm.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class BaseDialog extends JDialog {
        BaseDialog() {
            super();
            setModal(true);
        }

        // Overrides and calls (super)dispose method of JDialog - Nothing unusual
        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            Exception e = new Exception();
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("disposing");
            super.dispose();
        }
    }

    static class CaptureDialog extends BaseDialog implements ActionListener {
        CaptureDialog() {
            super();
            JButton btnInventory = new JButton("Close Me");
            btnInventory.addActionListener(this);
            add(btnInventory);
            setTitle("Recapture");
            setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setResizable(false);
            setSize(200, 80);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Clicked the button!");
            dispose();
        }
    }

    static class MainForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        MainForm() {
            super("Example");
            JButton btnCapture = new JButton();
            btnCapture.setText("Capture");
            btnCapture.addActionListener(this);
            add(btnCapture);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setSize(200, 80);
        }

        // Only one button is added to action listener ('if' not necessary)
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            new CaptureDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is evident if I run the application and then open and close/dispose the dialog. With the placement of the **Exception e** under **BaseDialog**'s "dispose" method I get the following output upon closing through the window's 'X' button (omitting internal calls):

```
java.lang.Exception
    at Main$BaseDialog.dispose(Main.java:24)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.processWindowEvent(JDialog.java:691)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2017)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1673)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1625)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at Main$CaptureDialog.<init>(Main.java:46)
    at Main$MainForm.actionPerformed(Main.java:71)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
disposing
disposing
java.lang.Exception
    at Main$BaseDialog.dispose(Main.java:24)
    at java.awt.Window.disposeImpl(Window.java:1161)
    at java.awt.Window$1DisposeAction.run(Window.java:1189)
    at java.awt.Window.doDispose(Window.java:1210)
    at java.awt.Window.dispose(Window.java:1151)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.dispose(SwingUtilities.java:1814)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.windowClosed(SwingUtilities.java:1792)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2061)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.processWindowEvent(JDialog.java:683)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2017)
```

Also notice that if you run the application and 'open - close' the dialog repeatedly, the method calls increment by 1 (best visible if you comment out the first two lines under the overridden 'dispose' method regarding the exception stacktrace printing and watch the output).

Here is a hard-stripped version if you would want to use/look at and thank you in advance above all!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainForm();
    }

    static class BaseDialog extends JDialog {
        BaseDialog() {
            super();
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            new Exception().printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("disposing");
            super.dispose();
        }
    }

    static class MainForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        MainForm() {
            super();
            JButton btnCapture = new JButton();
            btnCapture.setText("Capture");
            btnCapture.addActionListener(this);
            add(btnCapture);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(200, 80);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            new BaseDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Possibly helpful information:

1. Omitting 'super.dispose()' causes 'dispose' to be invoked only once - the application code should not be the issue.
2. If I extend JFrame instead of JDialog (regarding BaseDialog class), the dispose method is called properly (with super.dispose()).
3. Sort of irrelevant, but a 'hack' is to make a private field under the BaseDialog class:

->    private boolean disposed = false;

And then make a check when calling the dispose method:

```
@Override
public void dispose() {
    if (!disposed) {
        disposed = true;
        super.dispose();
    }
}
```

While it MAY solve the issue, it is far from a good answer and future problems may easily exist since the core is not fixed properly.

Comment: I was unavailable to respond, but now I am here. I reformatted the code (which I couldn't do yesterday quick enough, as I had to get up and was tired of trying to fix the issue) and uploaded a short, working example. Now it shouldn't be as confusing as it was before.

Comment: Print out the `hashCode()` from the dispose method to see what instances are being called. Each time the new instance is called twice, and every older instance is called once.

Comment: You might need to delve into source code to solve this as I cannot see a reason for its occurrence yet.

Comment: Currently trying to go through it and so far am out of luck. Am trying to locate the culprit using a plentiful of breakpoints in different places, but as before, no luck yet. It may be of use to some to mention that if I omit "super.dispose()" the overridden method is called once, so the application on its own should be rid of flaws in the code itself and I am starting to doubt there is an issue somewhere in the core libraries...

Comment: I meant going through the Java core library source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent window holds a reference to the dialog and will re-dispose of the dialog when it itself is disposed.

Your problem is that you're not assigning a parent window for the dialog, and so for some reason when the dialog is disposed it re-dosposes all dialog references previously made, as if the base class holds the references to the child window. You can solve the issue by passing the parent window into the dialog's super constructor, like so:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {

    // Creates the main frame (MainForm extends JFrame)
    private static MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainForm.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class BaseDialog extends JDialog {
        BaseDialog(Window win) {
            super(win);
            setModal(true);
        }

        // Overrides and calls (super)dispose method of JDialog - Nothing
        // unusual
        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            Exception e = new Exception();
            // e.printStackTrace();
            String text = String.format("Disposing. This hashCode: %08X", hashCode());
            System.out.println(text);
            super.dispose();
        }
    }

    static class CaptureDialog extends BaseDialog implements ActionListener {
        CaptureDialog(Window win) {
            super(win);
            JButton btnInventory = new JButton("Close Me");
            btnInventory.addActionListener(this);
            add(btnInventory);
            setTitle("Recapture");
            setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setResizable(false);
            setSize(200, 80);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Clicked the button!");
            dispose();
        }
    }

    static class MainForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        MainForm() {
            super("Example");
            JButton btnCapture = new JButton();
            btnCapture.setText("Capture");
            btnCapture.addActionListener(this);
            add(btnCapture);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setSize(200, 80);
        }

        // Only one button is added to action listener ('if' not necessary)
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new CaptureDialog(MainForm.this);
        }
    }
}
```

Myself, I avoid re-creating the dialog if I think that I might need it, which would prevent unnecessary accumulation of references. See code below and comment and uncomment the section indicated to see what I mean:

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainSimple extends JPanel {
    private JDialog dialog;

    public MainSimple() {
        add(new JButton(new OpenDialogAction("Open Dialog", KeyEvent.VK_O)));
        add(new JButton(new DisposeAction("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_X)));
    }

    private class OpenDialogAction extends AbstractAction {
        public OpenDialogAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean test = true;
            // test = (dialog == null); // ***** comment or uncomment this line *****
            if (test) {
                Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MainSimple.this);
                dialog = new MyDialog(win);
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(win);
            }
            dialog.setVisible(true);            
        }
    }

    private class MyDialog extends JDialog {

        public MyDialog(Window win) {
            super(win, "My Dialog", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            add(new JButton(new DisposeAction("Close", KeyEvent.VK_C)));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            String text = String.format("Disposing. This hashCode: %08X", hashCode());
            System.out.println(text);
            super.dispose();
        }
    }

    private class DisposeAction extends AbstractAction {

        public DisposeAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Component source = (Component) e.getSource();
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(source);
            win.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MainSimple mainPanel = new MainSimple();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Again, note that the parent JFrame holds references to all dialogs created, whether they've been disposed or not, and re-disposes them all on closing.

Comment: Yes that does seem to solve the problem quite well now. Also, as a side question, what way would you advise to research when it comes to showing up dialogs sequentially? Such as going through different steps for user input to take place and managing visibility of parent dialogs? Or is that probably for a different thread? Either way, thank you for the help!

Comment: Just a simple case I thought of is say I have one dialog with a button. Upon clicking the button, I want it to open up a second dialog while hiding the first (so it does not get in the way visually) and when I close the second to show the first one again without letting execution outside the first dialog's scope continue in between? Again, this is probably best off with a separate thread, if you believe so.

Comment: @Smokesick: Probably the base JFrame would be the parent window of this example since the first dialog is not visible. But myself, I'd probably show one dialog and swap views via a CardLayout.

Comment: Yeah, sounds similar to my case. So final question - do you think that having a master (invisible) frame, used just for a sequence of different frames is a good way to go about it? Every frame would be instantiated (not visible) and when a frame closes, using a WindowListener the next one to open up would be decided (including necessary calculations in-between like setting important variables)? Or is it still best to go about using the CardLayout?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but still I think it'd be helpful to someone.

I had the same problem and checking the docs for the [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog()) I discovered for the constructor without parameters documentation says

> NOTE: This constructor does not allow you to create an unowned JDialog. To create an unowned JDialog you must use either the JDialog(Window) or JDialog(Dialog) constructor with an argument of null.

So I simply tried using the [`JDialog(Window)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog(java.awt.Window)) or [`JDialog(Dialog)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog(java.awt.Dialog)) and it worked!

I just had to write this code

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog {
    public MyDialog() {
        super((Window)null);
    }
}
```

It might be helpful if you can't access the JFrame that should be the parent (which was my case)